# Letter/symbol frequency (PHP)

Tags: php, variables

How to get the frequency of a letter or symbol in a php script from a string.

I'm trying to make some sort of anagram maker for Web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

but watch out, cause this:

```
$text = 'This is a test';
echo substr_count($text, 'is'); // returns 2 occurences
```

returns 2 instead of 1, so if you want to check on words use:

```
$text = 'This is a test';
echo substr_count($text, ' is '); // returns 1 occurence
```